# How to write Nhibernate Queries

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate

I have two class in which are mapped in the database. The tables have primary and foreign key relation with each other with the field "DeptId".

**Employee.cs**

```
 public class Employee: Entity
    {
        public virtual Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Gender { get; set; }
        public virtual Int32 Age { get; set; }
        public virtual string Designation { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public virtual int CreatedById { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public virtual int? LastModifiedById { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }
```

**Department.cs**

```
public class Department
    {
        public virtual int DeptId { get; set; }
        public virtual string DeptName { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Enabled { get; set; }
    }
```

As i am new to NHibernate, i am unable to write the more complex Linq queries using QueryOver. I have written the following query but how can i write the more advance queries. please provide me sample queries and references for this.

```
var query = Session.QueryOver<Employee>().List();
```

Comment: For the most part, you can use LINQ.. what have you tried? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to implement the joins and use the inbuilt functions like Average Sum etc of NHibernate.

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow ;) NHibernate is great tool, please do not give up! ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The documentation for NHibernate querying is pretty good and complete. The basic knowledge you can find here:

- Chapter [15. Criteria Queries](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria)

The `QueryOver` API, which is the fully typed version of `Criteria` is documented here:

- Chapter [16. QueryOver Queries](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover)

Start to observe the API documentation. Soon you will see that it is pretty logic (`.Where()` to build WHERE, `.Select()` to adjust SELECT....). Later, *if any issues*, SO is full of HOW TO

An example from 16.1 adjusted to Employee:

```
var list = session
        .QueryOver<Employee>()
        .WhereRestrictionOn(c => c.Age).IsBetween(18).And(60)
        .Select(c => c.Name)
        .OrderBy(c => c.Name).Asc
        .List<string>();
```

A JOIN to Department (adjusted example from 16.4)

```
var query = session
        .QueryOver<Employee>()
        .JoinQueryOver(e => e.Department)
            .Where(k => k.DeptName == "Director");
```

Comment: Those links for the chapters are now dead.

Comment: the links for the chapters are working again

Answer (score 1):

Simple LINQ Queries are treated as NHibernate queries, but you have to connect them to repositories.

Connect entities with Repository and IRepository to reduce its complexities.

And it will be more structured.

Use this link to understand the connection between entity and repository.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Let me know if I have taken you to right track or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full samples

```
using DB.Extensions;
using DB.Modellers;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db;
using FluentNHibernate.Conventions;
using FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Cfg.MappingSchema;
using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode;
using NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace DB
{
    public class DatabaseAdapter
    {
        public List<IConvention> DatabaseConventions { get; set; }
        ISessionFactory sessionFactory;
        public string SqlFilePath { get; }
        public DatabaseAdapter(string sqlFilePath)
        {
            this.SqlFilePath = sqlFilePath;
            if (sessionFactory == null)
                sessionFactory = InitializeSessionFactory();
        }
       
        public ISession GetSession()
        {
            // For now, this will create a new session - However, eventually we could re-use sessions within threads, HTTP request context, etc
            return sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }

        public IStatelessSession GetStatelessSession()
        {
            return sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession();
        }
        ISessionFactory InitializeSessionFactory()
        {
             //var conventions = new IConvention[]
             //{
             //    Table.Is(x => x.EntityType.Name.ToLowerInvariant()), // All table names are lower case
             //    ForeignKey.EndsWith("Id"), // Foreign key references end with Id
             //    DefaultLazy.Always() // Enable Lazy-Loading by default
             //}.Concat(DatabaseConventions.NeverNull()).ToArray();

             var config = Fluently.Configure()
               .Database(GetMonoSQLConfiguration())
               .Mappings(m =>
               {
                   m.FluentMappings.Conventions.Setup(c => c.Add(AutoImport.Never()));
                   m.FluentMappings.Conventions.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                   m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

                   var assembly = Assembly.Load("DB");
                   m.FluentMappings.Conventions.AddAssembly(assembly);
                   m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(assembly);
                   m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssembly(assembly);
               });
            var nhConfig = config.BuildConfiguration();
            var session = config.BuildSessionFactory();
            return session;
        }
        
        private IPersistenceConfigurer GetMonoSQLConfiguration()
        {
            var sql = SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile(this.SqlFilePath)
             .ShowSql();
            return sql;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (sessionFactory != null)
                sessionFactory.Dispose();
        }

        public void SaveUpdate()
        {
            using (var session = GetSession())
            {
                using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    var existingItem = session.QueryOver<books>()
                       .Where(p => p.number == 1)
                       .Where(p => p.human == "U")
                       .SingleOrDefault();

                    if (existingItem != null) // Update existing
                    {
                        existingItem.number = 1;
                        session.Update(existingItem);
                    }
                    else // Create 
                    {
                        session.Save(new books());
                    }
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
        public IEnumerable<books> GetBooks()
        {
            using (var session = GetStatelessSession())
            {
                var books = session.QueryOver<books>().List();
                return books;
            }
        }
        public IEnumerable<chapters> GetChapters(books books)
        {
            using (var session = GetStatelessSession())
            {
                var items = session.QueryOver<chapters>().Where(p=>p.reference_human == books.human).List();
                return items;
            }
        }
        public IEnumerable<verses> GetVerses()
        {
            using (var session = GetStatelessSession())
            {
                var items = session.QueryOver<verses>().List();
                return items;
            }
        }
    }
}
```